# Highcharts scatter XY chart; color gradient as a function of a third variable

Tags: highcharts, scatter-plot, linear-gradients

I have a web application where display data from a server that sends data in arrays of variables: var X: {X0,X1,..,Xn}.

Right now if I want to create a XY chart in Highcharts I zip the X and Y array: Plot Data:{[X0,Y0],[X1,Y1],...,[Xn,Yn]}.

There is an easy way to color each point in a color gradient function of a third variable? (C:{{C0,C1,..,Cn}). From a given Cmin to Cmax.

Thans for your time,

Héctor

Comment: Take a look at this topic: https://www.highcharts.com/forum/viewtopic.php?t=31091

Is that what you had in mind?

Comment: Sorry for the delay. Something like the last proposal. But it seems a little bit difficult to make it work in a gradient from red to blue. Also the color axis doesn't seem to work properly when the points are hover. This is the only way?

Comment: Could you reproduce your attempt to show why color axis doesn't work properly?